# How to get a CheckBox value in MVC C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

[This is my view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXoVS.png)

I'm starting with MVC C#.

Sorry if this is an a very easy question.

I'm trying to get a CheckBox value from the view. The idea is put some checkboxes on the view, convert these values to Int32, to concatenate on a string entity for afterlly save in my DB.
The checkboxes should not be linked to the model.

Could someone explain me how to do it and how to link the checkbox to the controller? I'm very confused.

This is my model.

```
namespace Crossdock.Models{
public class Roles
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RolID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Usuario")]
    public string  Descripcion  { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Permisos")]
    public string  Permisos  { get;set;}


    //Permisos a validar por Área
    //Guías
    public bool GeneracionGuias { get; set; }
    //CEDIS
    public bool RecepcionPaquetes { get; set; }
    public bool CrossdockTemporal { get; set; }
    //Administración
    public bool Catalogos { get; set; }
}
```

}

This is my controller code. Here is where i need parse the bool values from the model to int/string and concatenate for save on "Descripcion" string field.

```
// GET: Roles/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Roles cl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        var rl = new Roles
        {
            RolID = 0,
            Descripcion=cl.Descripcion,
            Permisos=cl.Permisos,
        };

        objRol.Alta_Roles(rl);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { area = "" });
    }
```

This is my Create View.

```
@model Crossdock.Models.Roles

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<hr />
<h1>Registrar Nuevo Perfil de Permisos</h1>
<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descripcion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Permisos, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Permisos, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Permisos, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h3>
                        Guías
                    </h3>

                    <span> | Generación de Guías: </span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.GeneracionGuias, true)

                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h3>
                        CEDIS
                    </h3>

                    <span> | Recepción de Paquetes: </span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RecepcionPaquetes, false)
                    <br />
                    <span> | Crossdock Temporal: </span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CrossdockTemporal, false)

                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h3>
                        Administración
                    </h3>

                    <span> | Catálogos: </span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Catalogos, false)

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}

<div>
    <br />
    @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Do you have code you can post? It helps those who want to answer better understand your situation. In addition, MVC in this case is vague, are you saying you are using Windows.Forms?

Comment: I don't get it. why you don't want to use models? isn't this why models exist in the first place? to link controllers and views data? And could you please add the code so we can elaborate more?

Comment: I edited the details about my question yet. Tyvm.

Comment: @MohammedAlwedaei i follow your recommendations and i modified my Model but idk what's the next step.

Comment: Now in the controller, you will be able to access the model.